# Is this a good log loss for multiclass regression?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, classification, regression, deep-learning

I have multiple classes to predict at once, so I see the problem as a non-linear regression on the binary labels/classes I have as true output.

That said, the loss function is a sum of the log losses of every label which is then averaged for each example in the batch. Here is my loss function:

```
prediction = tf.sigmoid(hidden_out)  # Prediction output, from 0.0 to 1.0

# Avoid infinite gradients for extreme cases
# by remapping the prediction from 0.005 to 0.995:
pred = prediction*0.99+0.005 

# Log loss: mean is on batch_size, sum is on labels: 
loss = tf.reduce_mean(
    tf.reduce_sum(
        - labels*tf.log(pred) - (1.0-labels)*tf.log(1.0-pred), 
        reduction_indices=1
    )
)
```

I suspect there is something wrong with this. I am trying to train a deep convolutional neural network with residual inception layers. I get some `NaN` values for the loss quickly with low learning rates.

Is my log loss correct? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a loss that is already implemented for multiclass logistic regression instead of your loss: [sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/nn.html#sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits). It was carefully designed to avoid numerical problems.

In addition, instead of clipping prediction, it might be better to clip gradients. See [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/contrib.layers.html#optimize_loss), for example.

Comment: Oh thanks a lot! I thought that this loss function only existed in the API for the `softmax` xent.